# Preserve line breaks from javascript string on paste into textarea

Tags: javascript

Seen similar questions on SE without an answer.

If I click the button in the code, I alert the string and it's formatted with line breaks in the alert. When the string is then pasted into the textarea, all line breaks are removed.

```js
function pasteText() {
    
  var theText = "a\nb\nc";
  alert(theText);
  document.getElementById("theText").innerText = theText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="theText"></textarea>
<br><button onclick="pasteText()">Click</button>
```

NOTE: This is only an issue in Firefox

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. I clicked the button, saw the alerted text on 3 lines and now see 3 separate lines of text inside of the textarea.

Comment: Agreed. It works with the line breaks.

Comment: I should note, the issue is on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use textContent instead of innerText

See snippet below

```js
function pasteText() {
    
  var theText = "a\nb\nc";
  alert(theText);
  document.getElementById("theText").textContent = theText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="theText"></textarea>
<br><button onclick="pasteText()">Click</button>
```

2. or innerHTML

```js
function pasteText() {
    
  var theText = "a\nb\nc";
  alert(theText);
  document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML = theText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="theText"></textarea>
<br><button onclick="pasteText()">Click</button>
```